# Laravel 5 route binding variables not accessible in query builder

Tags: php, laravel, variables, binding, routes

I'm using route binding to determine if each part of the URL is related to the previous. I'm trying to access the route parameter/variable ($stage_number) in my query builder but no luck. To confuse things, if I substitute the variable with a hard value it works, e.g. 4

How do I use the $stage_number variable in my query?

```
/*
 * Route
 */
Route::get('/application/{application_id}/stage/{stage_number}', [
    'as' => 'application.stage',
    'uses' => 'ApplicationController@stage'
]);

/*
 * Route Service Provider
 */
// Application
$router->bind('application_id', function($application_id)
{
    $application = Application::find($application_id);

    if (! $application)
    {
        abort(404);
    }

    return $application;
});

// Stage
$router->bind('stage_number', function($stage_number)
{
    $application = $this->getCurrentRoute()->application_id;

    $stage = collect($application->stages)->where('order', $stage_number)->all();

    if (! $stage)
    {
        abort(404);
    }

    return $stage;
});
```

**Update in response to [patricus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35513217/4037322):**

Thanks for the information about calling `where()` on collections; I did not realise it handled differently to the query builder. Updating my `where()` for the collection works perfectly - thanks. However, I am still having trouble when using the query builder:

```
// Route with data
/application/1/stage/4

// Actual data returned
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Information about the University or Education Course"
    "order" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Information about your education to date"
    "order" => 4
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Other Information"
    "order" => 5
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Declaration"
    "order" => 6
  ]
]

// Desired data to be returned
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Information about your education to date"
    "order" => 4
  ]
]
```

Regardless of what `order` I specify in my route I seem to get everything returned that `is not null` unless I choose `1` or `2` (which are rows with no order number and excluded from the array example above) and then I get that row returned with all of the other rows that `is not null` (as shown in the example above) but any other `null` rows are excluded. Is this a problem caused by the relationship on my `Application` object?

```
public function stages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\Application\Stage', 'type_id')->orWhereNull('type_id')->orderBy('order', 'asc');
}
```

**Update:**

Setting the `foreign_key` and `local_key` on my relationship seemed to resolve the other issues:

```
public function stages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\Application\Stage', 'type_id', 'type_id')->orWhereNull('type_id')->orderBy('order', 'asc');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually calling the `where()` method on a `Collection` object, not on a `Builder` object.

The `where()` method on the `Collection` works a little differently. First, it can only do an equals comparison. Second, by default, it does a strict equals (`===`) comparison, and this is your issue. Since your `$stage_number` is a string, and your `order` field is most likely an integer, the strict comparison doesn't return any results.

You can change the comparison to a loose equals (`==`) by passing `false` as the third parameter. You can also use the `whereLoose()` method, which does the same thing.

Also note, assuming that `stages` is a `hasMany` or `belongsToMany` relationship on the `Application` object, there is no need for the call to `collect()`. `$application->stages` will already return a `Collection`.

```
// pass false as third parameter
$stage = $application->stages->where('order', $stage_number, false)->all();

// or use whereLoose
$stage = $application->stages->whereLoose('order', $stage_number)->all();
```

Now, having said all that, you probably want to be calling `where()` on the query builder. While `$application->stages` will give a `Collection` of related stage objects, `$application->stages()` returns the `Relation` object for the relationship, which gives you access to the query builder. Since you have access to the builder, you can add your where clause to the query being run and will provide a performance boost (and also doesn't care about variable type).

```
$stage = $application->stages()->where('order', $stage_number)->get();
```

Note that `get()` will return a `Collection` object that contains the matching stage objects. If `order` is unique and you want to get that one stage object, you can use `first()` instead of `get()`:

```
$stage = $application->stages()->where('order', $stage_number)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. Please see my question update.